# Python Append leaving last entry in dataframe only

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a function which connects through a DB system and then passes the values through in the below image:

[image: Example]

Next, I have used my function and iterated through this below:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([])
df_master = [] #Convert this to a list instead of a PD Dataframe

for i in PI_tags:
    df_tmp = df_tmp.append(ReadPiValues(i, interval, start_date, end_date))
    df_master.append(df_tmp)
```

My understanding is that with how append works, it should **NOT** be over-writing data but simply appending this to the dataframe. However,
rather than appending, it seems to over-write the data-frame.

I can't understand why this is the case however.
I have read a large number of the SO questions related to Append but have not reached a successful conclusion.

Could anyone please advise what I may have misunderstood?

PS: I have also tried using lists instead of dataframes, but this has also not worked. I have also referred to the documentation but couldn't see the problem in my implementation (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

EDIT: *Updated Code re: tmp to df_tmp*
This does not actually update df_master however as it appears blank.
[image]

EDIT2: I have changed df_master to a list which seems to return a list of lists. However, for Pandas Dataframes, it will immediately return a blank ____.

I don't quite understand why it seems we can't append another dataframe to another one when I know in previous cases, this has worked.

EDIT3: As mentioned above, changing df_master from a dataframe to a list allows me to receive the data in a nested list [xx,yy],[xx,yy] as per the image below.
However, **I now need to work out a suitable approach to unpack this into a dataframe.**

[image]

Comment: @AidanGawronski - The PI Tag is simply a list of PI attributes. From the loop, we can see when we print this out, the looping is occurring. Also, the fact that we are receiving valid outputs (specifically the last attribute entry), indicates it is working. It is just over-writing for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to grab a list and append it to the end of a dataframe, why not initialize df_tmp with the data, like this:

```
df_master = pd.DataFrame([])

for i in PI_tags:
    df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(ReadPiValues(i, interval, start_date, end_date))
    df_master = df_master.append(df_tmp)
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an typo earlier. I had fixed this in an earlier iteration. Unfortunately, this doesn't actually populate the dataframe df_master.
 It leaves it blank which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- `append` isn't happening in place, so you need to assign it back to `df_master`.

Comment: Hey, great thought. When you make this assigned to df_master, it will only retain the last element in the dataframe. it won't retain the previous ith entries.

Hence, the problem I am dealing with. :( Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Updated my answer again.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks again for your input. Unfortunately even with that novel approach ( I do like it ) it still returns the last element in the data frame as per the image above sadly. I'm trying to wrack my brains and work out why. There is definitely a reason.